# custom search in combine dropdown menu with onchange submit for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

now im making wordpress project in my local pc. i have to make custom search using dropdown menu with onchange submit. here is my code. but the problem is. the result won't go to search.php.

```
<form method="get" id="form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
            <div class="column_select_block">
                    <div class="column_select_box">
                        <p class="column_select_title">CATEGORY:</p>
                        <select class="column_select" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="category">
                            <option value="">ALL</option>
                            <?php
                                $categories = get_categories();
                                foreach($categories as $category):
                                    echo '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
                                endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column_select_box">
                        <p class="column_select_title">TAG:</p>
                        <select class="column_select" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="tag">
                            <option value="">ALL</option>
                            <?php
                                $tags = get_tags();
                                foreach($tags as $tag):
                                    echo '<option value="'.$tag->term_id.'">'.$tag->name.'</option>';
                                endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

            </div>
            </form>
```

and second is. how do i can get the value from the link

```
http://localhost/<localporjectname>/?category=1&tag=4
```

i want to get the value from the "category" and "tag"

could someone help me to figure out this.?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a text field that have attribute name='s'

```
 <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
```

Either you can use hidden field if you doesn't want any text search box

```
 <input type="hidden" name="s" id="search" value="" />
```